# Is it possible to have different stylesheets for the different locales that my site is translated (localized) to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, yaml, haml

I'm in the process of abstracting the strings out of the views of my project. As I'm doing so I'm testing out what different languages look like.

In languages that are rendered in the Latin-style alphabet I want to have a style that prevents orphans (a single word on the last line of a wrapping string). And in some places I want to trigger wrapping so that things consistently appear on two lines or one line.

However, I'm pretty sure (not definitely sure since I don't speak chinese) that I don't want to wrap Chinese. Ideally, I'd even like to display the Chinese in right-to-left reading order.

Is it possible to have different display code for different languages (locales)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes.

You can target elements per language with the [`:lang` pseudo selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:lang), there is also an experimental `:dir` selector but support is limited.

In Rails you could load an additional locale specific stylesheet like this:

```
# app/helpers/style_helper.rb
module StyleHelper
  def locale_stylesheet_link_tag(locale = I18n.locale)
     path = Rails.root.join('app', 'assets', 'stylesheets')
     if Dir.glob(path + "#{locale}.{css, scss, sass, less}").any?
       stylesheet_link_tag(locale.to_s)
     end
  end
end
```

---

```
# app/layouts/application.html.erb

<head>
  ...
  <%= locale_stylesheet_link_tag %>
</head>
```

What this does is load `en.css` if the locale is `en` and an `en.css` file exists in `app/assets/stylesheets`.

Comment: Thanks! This is so helpful.

Comment: I will try it this afternoon

Comment: I have not had time to test this but I'm going to mark it as answered. I'll come back and share when I've tested it out. Thanks!!!